# Get the number of elements returned by Promise on ionic framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, get

I'm getting data from API in a providers, and I want to display the details of element from this endpoint :  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3

I'm fetching data with Promise method and I want to get the element by id in other method like that:

```
getPostByID(id){
    for( var i=0; i < ( this.getPosts().length ); i++){
      if (this.getPosts[i].id == id) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.getPosts[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

The method that get all data is:

```
getPosts(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(URLS.POSTS).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err =>{
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

I got this error:

> Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Promise<{}>'.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all. There's no `length` on `Promise<T>`. You need to return the promise from your `getPostByID` method. I suggest [reading about `Promise` and how it works](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).

```
  getPostByID(id){
    for( var i=0; i < ( this.getPosts().length ); i++){
      if (this.getPosts[i].id == id) {
        return this.getPosts[i]
      }
    }
  }
```

Now when you use this data, you need to use `.then`:

```
this.service.getPostByID(id).then(data => {
  this.post = data
})
```

And you can display it in the template:

```
{{ post | json }}
```

---

You might want to add some loading state while data is loading.

```
this.isLoading = true
this.service.getPostByID(id).then(data => {
  this.isLoading = false
  this.post = data
})
```

And in template:

```
<div class="loading" *ngIf="isLoading">Loading...</div>
<div class="content" *ngIf="!isLoading">
  {{ post | json }}
</div>
```

---

Also, it's more idiomatic in Angular to use Observables from RxJS than promises, so you should probably check out how that works -- it's not that different, but much more powerful.